# Customising XML tag with nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, nokogiri

I'm building an xml document using Nokogiri's XML Builder. I have a tag called

```
<InstAmt>
```

and I want it to be

```
<InstdAmt Ccy="Eur">
```

What do I need to add/configure to achieve this? I tried looking at the Nokogiri documentation but it only talks about attributes like class and id and that's not what I'm looking for.

The relevant portion of the builder looks like this:

```
            xml.PmtId{
              xml.EndToEndId "value"
              xml.InstdAmt "value"
              xml.ChrgBr "value"
            }
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes it does, but can't you just switch class for Ccy in those examples?

Comment: @Baloo I get a syntax error when I try that. I've tried xml.InstdAmt(:Ccy=>"Eur") and similar variations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass a hash to the method creatig the tag it will be used to create attributes:

```ruby
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
xml.PmtId{
  xml.EndToEndId "value"
  xml.InstdAmt "value", :Ccd => 'Eur'
  xml.ChrgBr "value"
}
end

puts builder.to_xml
```

produces:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PmtId>
  <EndToEndId>value</EndToEndId>
  <InstdAmt Ccd="Eur">value</InstdAmt>
  <ChrgBr>value</ChrgBr>
</PmtId>
```